# Change default location of ~/.R

Tags: r, environment-variables, rstudio, startup

So I have the following variables set in my `Renviron` file

```
R_ENVIRON_USER="~/.config/R/Renviron"
R_PROFILE_USER="~/.config/R/Rprofile"
R_MAKEVARS_USER="~/.config/R/Makevars"
R_HISTFILE="~/.local/share/Rhistory"
R_LIBS_USER="~/Library/R/3.6/library"
PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/X11/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/Cellar/cairo/1.16.0_2/lib/pkgconfig"
```

But I haven't been able to find an env variable to just change the directory of `~/.R`. Now whenever I start R, I end up with a new `~/.R` folder in my home directory. Is there a way to just change the default R user directory?

Comment: Why do you want to change the location of that file based on an env var? See https://csgillespie.github.io/efficientR/3-3-r-startup.html for one of many such articles that explain how this works. Your question is confusing since it seems like you want to retroactively change where other `R` config files are found.

Comment: @KurtisRader Huh? Im well aware of the process of how R starts up. I’m saying there are env vars for single startup files but no documented env var for a directory to house them in. Now I have two .R folders after Rstudio starts up.

Comment: You're probably looking for information about the[XDG specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html). Also, given your original problem statement I have no idea how have "two .R folders after Rstudio starts up." in light of my previous comment.